# Badge suggestion: Patient Zero

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

You had more than X questions marked as a duplicate of your question.

Could have bronze, silver and gold versions depending on X. Suggestions for names:

- Patient Zero
- Columbus’s Egg
- Dibs
- Did It First
- Naked Emperor Spotter
- Xerox PARC
- Jango Fett

Comment: Last thing I want is anything named "naked emperor spotter" tied to my account, but otherwise this seems like a great idea.

Comment: Added another one. If you know computing history you know why this applies. OK, it may not be admissible to name a badge after a company, or it may be too obscure.

Comment: What behavior does this encourage though? Congratulations, you were the lucky one that asked this question first? The opposite badges make sense because we want to encourage users to close duplicates, but this badge seems more based on luck. You can't know that people are going to keep asking the same question in thw future, and there's no real behavior to encourage here. This sounds like a "badges for the sake of badges" scenario.

Comment: "Think outside the box", I imagine. Question things that look obvious and plain to everybody.

Comment: @animuson oldest != original. Find a crappy frequent duplicate, write a better version and close the old one as a duplicate of yours. Or just spot a need for a new canonical.

Comment: What about those who go around closing all other questions as duplicates of theirs because they thought they were the only person able to uniquely, expertly answer it, and it wouldn't do to just do so on an existing, it needed to be under a new question they soft-lobbed?

Comment: @JanDvorak That is an *incredibly rare* scenario though. The vast majority of the badges that will be obtained from these criteria will be random questions that just happened to get linked as duplicates. Requiring that the source question be *newer* than the questions being linked to it would make for more interesting criteria, but I imagine it'd also narrow the scope of the badge to an incredibly small subset.

Comment: @animuson newer only + gold + "better than ever before" / "Q&A remastered" / etc?

Comment: Is the massive amount of upvotes for ridiculously simple questions not reward enough?

Comment: Unfortunately, if this were in place, I can see this exchange happening over and over: "Why did you ask this again?" "Well, I thought I had a better way to phrase this question since it didn't get picked up last time." "Yeah, right. BADGE WHORE! DOWNVOTES READY" (cc @JanDvorak)

Comment: @AnnaLear humans are going to suck no matter what SE does. Point taken, though.

Comment: Requiring a certain positive score on the master question would make this harder to game. Maybe "not self-answered" as well.

Comment: See no need in this badge. You can call it "Bronze random user", "Silver random user", "Gold random user", though.

Comment: @animuson How does this line of reasoning work when applied to badges rewarded based on views? Aren't those also luck?